# How to generate model objects from Json Schema / Json in xcode (swift)?

Tags: ios, iphone, json, swift, getter-setter

I have generated `Json(s)` for each java class using `Gson` library. Some of them are in hierarchy nature while others are completely independent. I am looking for a way to convert these Json to plain object (getter and setter methods) in `swift`. Is there any way to do it? For Java we can convert them using [JsonSchema2Pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Answer (score 5):

try [JSON4SWIFT](http://www.json4swift.com/).

I feel,thats the equivalent for jsonschema2pojo in java

Updated :

Try [QuickType](https://quicktype.io/),It even has a plugin for Xcode